# Circling certain dates in CalendarView without a custom library

Tags: android, calendar, calendarview

I have a simple `CalendarView` in my layout. All I'm trying is circling a set of dates. Searched for answers on StackOverflow, and almost all of them are suggesting some libraries, `CalDroid` being the most popular one.

Is it possible to do it without using any custom library as the need is very trivial?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing in `CalendarView` itself that offers what you want. So, your choices are:

1. Write your own calendar view, one that has your desired feature
2. Fork `CalendarView` and modify it to have your desired feature
3. Use a library that somebody else created that has your desired feature
4. Go without this "trivial" feature